# Is it safe to call Threads from Web Applications

Tags: tomcat, servlets, thread-safety

I'm having a web application (Servlet), where I get a Video (as a file) and I upload them into the YouTube. Any way What I have is creating a thread for file uploading into YouTube. I add the content into a queue and the thread will keep upload files until the queue finishes. The delay between each uploads are 1 min.

It works fine, until YouTube says your upload limit for hour is finished.

But if I make the interval between two uploads for 15 mins, and if I keep that interval by sleeping the thread will it be a problem in long run (assume there is a queue of 40 videos = 10 hours). Is there any best practice to develop such a scenario.

Comment: why do you want to change the interval?

Comment: If you keep uploading videos with 15 min intervals its very unlikely to refuse a video from YouTube API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A separate thread is inappropriate tool for such scenario. It sleeps most of its lifetime. Instead use [`Timer.schedule()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html#schedule%28java.util.TimerTask,%20long,%20long%29) with a properly set period. Your timing will be taken care of by a dedicated thread which already runs in the JVM for that purpose. What you have now as a `run()` of the `Thread`, just make it [`TimerTask`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/TimerTask.html).

Comment: sounds interesting, never used. Thank you.